# Git missed rebase for extended branch development?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, rebase

A few months ago I branched off of the master development branch in a project I'm working on.  I've been working on my own experiment branch, but constantly pulled in the changes from master to keep up to date.  Every time I did that I used this command set

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout experiment
git merge master
```

Today I went to merge my experiment branch back into master.  I simply made sure I was all up to date with master, and called

```
git checkout master
git merge experiment
```

When I look in GitX at the master branch, it shows a seperate line of development for what looks like every single time that I pulled from master to keep myself up to date.  Is this because I should've been rebasing master when I pulled the changes?

Does anyone have a decent solution to fix this?  I guess I could rebase experiment onto master?  But experiment is quite the branch, and I'd like to keep it as an obvious seperate branch in history.  Is there a way for me to go back and rebase the old problematic merges?
I'm pretty new to git as you can probably tell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly.

When you are performing a merge, you are in fact having one commit that is having 2 parents, what is happening is like this:

original history:

```
A <- B <- C
```

you changed something (X and Y)

```
A <- B <- C <- X <- Y
```

you pulled from tracked repository  (assuming someone added D and E)

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E
           ^
            \- X <- Y
```

and then you merged:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- M
           ^             /
            \- X <- Y <-/
```

That's why you see those "separate lines"

In case of rebase, it is something like this:

you pulled from tracked repository  (assuming someone added D and E)

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E
           ^
            \- X <- Y
```

You rebase (which means GIT applies your change X, Y again)

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- X' <- Y'
```

(revision X and Y is abandoned)

which I believe is what you like to see

Comment: OK, so how can I fix this?  Can I go back and rebase the old buggered merges?

Comment: if you are sure that all the merges are not yet published to public yet, you are free to do so.  I am not sure how Git handle rebase for the case with 'intermediate merges' but why not give it a try? you can always switch back to the place before rebase :)  For worse case, you just need to cherry pick each non-merge revision for rebase.  Anyway, you gotta make sure that all your changes are still local.  Once it is published, rebasing will ruin everything.